# Change rows & colums in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'd like to change the position of an element (image or usercontrol) in him changing its row and column in the event `PageOrientationChanged`" in code-behind.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the uielement is contained in a grid, you can use

```
Grid.SetRow(<your element>, <new row>)
Grid.SetColumn(<your element>, <new column>)
```